# UK: Questions to NON-EU tourists prior to reaching the border

Tags: customs-and-immigration, borders

PLEASE NOTE THAT THIS QUESTION IS NOT A DUPLICATE AS SUGGESTED. This deals with information provided BEFORE reaching the border.

Are international (NON-EU/EEA/SCHENGEN) tourists generally required before entering the UK at the border (so for instance, in their visa application/interview...) to provide any information at all about the person they're visiting (both in case they're staying at this person's place, or in case they're staying in a hotel) if they're coming to the UK to visit a family member or a friend?

In case of a positive answer to the above: is this information only provided orally, informally and off-the-records, or will a record be kept?

Comment: You already asked this question. Why post it again?

Comment: @ReddHerring, different questions, the others are about a different time. Like at the border crossing.

Comment: It seems like there's a question behind this, or an actual problem you're looking to solve by asking these questions, and it would help us help you to know what that is.

Answer (score 3):

There is no interview for a UK visa application, only an appointment to provide biometrics.

The visa application asks for accommodation details, if this is being provided by a friend for example, it is necessary to give the name of the individual, their address and the dates you’ll be staying there. It is also required to state whether the applicant has any family in the UK (irrespective of whether the applicant will be staying with them). This information will be recorded on file.

Comment: +1, just the OP should keep in mind that not all non-EU/EEA/Swiss nationals [need visas to visit the UK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_the_United_Kingdom#Non-visa_nationals), so many tourists will not be completing visa applications or providing any information prior to reaching the border.